# CURL API token request with grant_type=password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, request

I need to generate an API token for my app. The docs from the external service shows me below info:

```
This request uses normal post webforms.
<password> must be md5 encoded.

Endpoint: api/token
Request: "grant_type:   password
Password:   <password>
Username:   <USERNAME>
"
```

What I did was generate md5 encoded password in console:

```
> Digest::MD5.hexdigest("ZCW2OQo5yhfmTKutGjiCWQ==")
 => "53a89a22375a3665cfe4cb92ee17992b"
```

And put it into curl command like below:

```
curl -d "grant_type=password&password=53a89a22375a3665cfe4cb92ee17992b&username=my_user_name" -X POST https://enpoint/api/token
```

But instead of expected response I'm getting an error:

> {"error":"invalid_grant"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your password is already encoded in some way - it's a base64 encoding of a binary string.

Try to put your actual password instead of this already encoded version as argument of `hexdigest`.